# create new dictionary with existing dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary as:

```
a={'name':'jhonson','profession':'doctor','location':'new york'}
```

Now, All I want to create a new dictionary with key as `'doc_*counter'`. Something as:

```
new_dict={'doc_1':{'name':'jhonson'},'doc_2':{'profession':'doctor'},'doc_3':{'location':'new york'}}
```

What I did as:

```
count=0
new_dict={}
for k,v in a.items():
    count+=1
    new_dict['doc'+str(count)][k]=v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate():

> **Python enumerate()**
>
> The enumerate() method adds counter to an iterable and returns it (the enumerate object).

```
a={'name':'jhonson','profession':'doctor','location':'new york'}

new_dict = {}
for idx, key in enumerate(a.keys()):
    new_dict['doc_' + str(idx)] = {key: a[key]}

print (new_dict)
```

output:

```
{'doc_0': {'name': 'jhonson'}, 'doc_1': {'profession': 'doctor'}, 'doc_2': {'location': 'new york'}}
```

or just use list comprehension:

```
a={'name':'jhonson','profession':'doctor','location':'new york'}

new_dict = {'doc_' + str(idx): {key: a[key]} for (idx, key) in enumerate(a.keys())}
print (new_dict)
```

output:

```
{'doc_0': {'name': 'jhonson'}, 'doc_1': {'profession': 'doctor'}, 'doc_2': {'location': 'new york'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

And to add to the previous give answer. If you use `a.items()` in the enumerate. You can unpack the key value pairs in the dictionary.

```
a={'name':'jhonson','profession':'doctor','location':'new york'}

new_dict = {}
for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(a.items()): 
  new_dict['doc' + str(idx)] = {key: value}

print(new_dict)
```

This removes the extra lookup for the value of the key: `{key: a[key]}`.